# Protect formulas from shared users

Tags: google-sheets

I've created a shared Google Docs spreadsheet with many sheets.  On most all of the sheets columns F:H contain formulas that manipulate the data entered in other columns.   I want users to enter data in the non-formula columns and be able to add more rows when they need to.

- I've tried protecting the columns - but then users are unable to insert rows.
- I've tried creating a script that offers a menu to add rows - but then the users are told "You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit."

This would seem like a very simple need, protect formulas and allows users to insert rows. (Hopefully the formulas would be copied, but if not I could copy them in a script.)

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not a way for user to run a container-bound script as "you".  Does seem simple, but since another user can't create permissions that are above their authority, they can't create a new row with new protected cells. If you went through and protected each individual cell (instead of each range), they would be able to insert rows, but they wouldn't be able to run a script that copied down the formula and the protection.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364281/google-apps-script-is-it-possible-to-update-a-protected-range-from-a-script) is a similar discussion, there could be a different way to get at what you want.  There could a solution for you based on cell validation, which can be copied in a new row.  A web-app can be run as you, but that's getting into a different kind of project.

Comment: Thanks for you thoughts.  But, there must be some way to achieve a shared spreadsheet that has a locked column (or range of cells) and still allows users to add more rows.   I can't imagine I am the only person that needs this.